# Software to create robot schema

Tags: software-recommendation, diagram

I have a question regarding a picture below. Any idea what software might have been used to draw these?

[image]

Comment: It could be pretty much anything. Do you have any other criteria, other than this? which is basically just a drawing....

Answer (score 2):

A pair of Delta robots, my favorite subject. As for what software, any vector graphics tool would be fine:

- Adobe Illustrator
- Inkscape
- Corel Draw
- Xara Designer
- ...

Any CAD application:

- Autocad
- Catia
- ...

Mathematical applications like:

- Geogebra
- Mathematica
- Octave/matlab
- ...

Programming languages:

- Python
- Postscript
- C
- ...

[image]

**Image 1**: An animation of a hypothetical Delta robot, in a isometric view, made with pyQT for a lecture a few years back.

Comment: "Any vector graphics tool" - sure, but the exact same picture can be drawn with Photoshop. (The lines seem antialiased so I think that rules out MS Paint.)

Comment: Yes, @RadLexus but then you could not print the image and you would do extra work for a inferior result.

Comment: OP does not mention "print" ... and the small, heavily pixelated and antialiased look of the sample image may be *exactly* what OP was going for. Really, despite your quite exhaustive list it's just a plain bad question.

Comment: No but theres no reason why you cant get both. But the image is clearly from a vector source or a super pedant has been doing the drawing.